# Not able to override button style from app.xaml in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style, app.xaml

I stuck in very strange problem and I could not find solution to it. I tried almost all the possible ways (even delete and recreate solution) to solve this.

**ISSUE**

I am trying to override default style of control in a WPF app. I defined all the resouces and styles in `App.xaml`. Problem is, a button foreground color is not getting override runtime. Suprisingly, it show overriden color (White) in VS designer but when I run app, it becomes black (may be default).

There is no other code in app that changes button style.

Additional Info : Buttons are in a Usercontrol and its loaded on MainWindow's ContentControl.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="#000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ActiveBrush" Color="#3A71C5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBrush" Color="#0071C5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressBrush" Color="#3A8BF4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultBrush" Color="#0071F9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#F4F4F4"/>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

**Buttons in VS Designer**

[image]

**Buttons in app runtime**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue could be that you have some other style which gets applied to some nested control of your button (e.g. `TextBlock`).

I pasted your snippet in a sample WPF app and wrapped a `Button` in a custom `UserControl`. I tested it and showed correctly in both design view and runtime.

Then I added the following style in `App.xaml`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

and the button was showing red text.

So the problem could be some other style for *other* controls which is overriding some parts of your `Button` template.

---

**EDIT**

A possible solution could be to explicitly define the Button content in the control itself:

```xml
<Button>
    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}">Test</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but I couldn't come up with anything else at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you propose any solution? How to achieve this when we have this scenario (two styles to change default control style (button and textblock together))?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a possible solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any way to achieve this by making change to style or template? I do not want to change all the UI Buttons. :(  I am trying to create theme for application.

Comment: If you're sure that you will only have text in your buttons, you could apply the solution I proposed directly in the `ControlTemplate` you defined in the `Style`. It's not a really good solution imo, but it should work until someone else suggests a better approach.